# How to align multiple views correctly

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder

Hi I want to make an UI with a search bar immediately under the battery indicator and two UIViews vertically aligned below the search bar. The heigh of the two views are same and should take up the rest of the screen. I tried to add constraint to the views but their size either exceed the screen boundary or leave blank margins. What is the best way to achieve this? My app is targeting iOS 6 so no stack view please:)

Here's the screenshot of my current layout:

[image: Screenshot]

The views exceed the right side boundary and there is a white stripe between them. I tried adding constraint to set both left and right margin to be zero, but still get the incorrect size.

Comment: try to use container ........

Comment: AutoLayout is the right choice. Maybe you haven't applied it correctly. It's better if you share the design screen here so that someone can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `Autolayout` constraints are as follow:

The `topView` should have:

- **Leading**, **Top**, and **Trailing** - to the `TopLayoutGuidelines`
- **Equal Height** and **Bottom** (or **Vertical Space**) - to the `bottomView`

---

The `bottomView` should have:

- **Leading**, **Top**, **Trailing**, and **Equal Height** - to the `firstView`
- **Bottom** - to the `BottomLayoutGuidelines`

Comment: Like this? bottomView.leading = topView.leading topView.bottom = bottomView.top

Comment: Along with the `leading` and `trailing` drag from the `topView` to `bottomView` and select `Vertical Spacing` and `Equal Height`

Answer (score 0):

1.Set equal width for both view && equal height.

2. set vertical space between the two view.
3. set leading,trailing ,top space to the view &&bottom space for one view .

4.set center horizontal for the view.

5. set leading and trailing for the view2 to view1.

***better you set the equal width to your view***